# Will connecting my Mavic Pro to a an iPad Litchi app try to update my Mavic Pro firmware?

Tags: software, smartphone-app, dji-mavic-pro-1

I have an iPad that I keep offline and use the DJI Go app with.  If I install Litchi, return the iPad to offline mode and connect it to my Mavic Pro will it try to update my Mavic Pro firmware?   Is the litchi app compatible with all versions of DJI firmware?

Comment: Vote for Litchi as a possible tag.  Maybe third-party-app?

Answer (score 3):

An updated or new Litchi installation will not work with outdated firmware.  The drone will not connect until there is internet communication.   Once connected it seems it will not request updates or nag.